# What happends at backend when we alter a table in hive

Tags: hive, bigdata, partitioning, hadoop-partitioning

When we alter a table in hive like changing the partition. what happens to the table. Does it reformat the table or it creates a new data for new partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only the metadata is changed, hive doesn't change data i.e underlying files in any way. if you added a new partition you need to ensure that the data is already under the mapped partition directories.